# Can polymorphysim be achieved using composition instead of inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, composition

I am learning Java. I know what inheritance and composition are. I have seen numerous examples of polymorphism using inheritance, so my first question is: Can the same be done using composition? If so, what would be an example?

My second question is: Is polymorphism basically method overloading and/or method overriding? If yes, then why?

Answer (score 4):

### First question

Polymorphism can be achieved in Java in two ways:

- Through *class inheritance*: `class A extends B`
- Through *interface implementation*: `class A implements C`.

In the later case, to properly implement A's behaviour, it can be done though *composition*, making A delegate over some other class/es which do the tasks specified in Interface C.

Example: Let's suppose we have already some class imeplementing interface C:

```
class X implements C
{
    public String getName() {...}
    public int getAge() {...}
}
```

How can we create a new class implementing C with the same behaviour of X? Like this:

```
class A implements C
{
    private C x=new X();
    public String getName() {return x.getName();}
    public int getAge() {return x.getAge();}
}
```

### Second question

No, polymorphism is not method overloading and/or method overriding (in fact, overloading has nothing to do with Object Oriented Design):

- Method *overloading* consists on creating a new method with the same name that some other (maybe inherited) method in the same class but with a different signature (=parameter numbers or types). Adding new methods is OK, but that is not the aim of polymorphism.
- Method *overriding* consists on setting a new body to an inherited method, so that this new body will be executed in the current class instead of the inherited method's body. This is a advantage of polymorphism, still is not the base of it either.

Polymorphism, in brief, is the ability of a class to be *used* as different classes/interfaces.

Comment: In java, there are 2 types of polymorphism,compile time and run time, method overloading is example of compile time, and method overiding is example of run time, is there not any interelationship b/w these 2 things? (overloading/overiding and polymorphism ). Please bare with me, im still in learning stage, if i am confusing myself then please let me know.

Comment: @calculusnoob I'm afraid you are confused: In Java there is just one polymorphism, and it is always based on the declarations of the source code. In brief: At compile time, you (=the programmer) decide how a class _can be_ used. And, at run time, the program itself decides how the class _is_ actually used.

Comment: `https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-guide-to-polymorphism-in-java/` 
I stated the types of polymorphism (in JAVA)from this website.Is the info given there wrong ? Or am I interpreting it wrong ?

Comment: Regarding your first question, can you explicitly define why polymorphysim cannot be achived using composition ?

Comment: @calculusnoob You interpreted it right, but I do not agree with that blog's contents: It is confusing and states wrong principles. I recommend you [Oracle's official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) and also [this other one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm).

Comment: @calculusnoob Regarding the first question, I stated that polymorphism **can be** achieved through composition.

Comment: "Polymorphism can be achieved in Java in two ways:" - You only listed one (inclusion polymorphism); there are actually three: ad-hoc (method/operator overloading), inclusion (inheritance), and parametric (generic types) polymorphism

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. Polymorphism and composition or aggregation (composition is a more rigid form of aggregation wherein the composed objects' lifetimes are tied together) are different ways of reusing classes.

Composition involves aggregating multiple objects to form a single entity. Polymorphism involves multiple objects that share analogous behavior.

For example, a Car object might be *composed* of two Axle objects, a Chassis object, four Wheel objects (which themselves may be composed of a Rim, a Tire, six LugNuts and so on). When you instantiate a Car, your Car constructor would instantiate all the parts that go along with it. That's composition. (Aggregation would use all the same part objects but not necessarily instantiate them in its constructor.)

A Car object might also not be useful on its own, but rather as a blueprint for numerous more specialized *implementations* of cars, such as SportsCar, SUVCar, SedanCar, and the like. In this case, the Car object might define a Car *interface* that would define common behaviors such as Steer, HitTheGas and Brake, but leave the implementations of those behaviors to the implementing classes. Then, a consumer of a Car object can declare an object of type Car, instantiate it as any of the implementing classes such as SportsCar, call the methods defined in the Car interface, and get the behavior implemented in the instantiated class. That's polymorphism.

For a decent tutorial on both, with some comparisons, have a look at [this](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3b_oopinheritancepolymorphism.html). Keep in mind that the UML diagrams have an inaccuracy: while the examples do indeed describe composition as opposed to aggregation, the related UML class diagrams have white diamonds where they should be black. UML class diagram syntax uses a white diamond for class associations that are aggregations and a black one for those that are compositions.

Also, [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance) has some good information, in particular tdammers's answer halfway down the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is book answer, if one remember about all the firemans are fireman but some are drivers, chiefs etc. There you need polymorphism. There is things you can do with classes and it's a general idea in OOP as language constraints. Overriding is just what you can do with classes. Also permissions and local and/or global scopes. There is default constructor for any class. There is namespace scope, program, class etc.

*All Classes and methods are functions but not all functions are methods*

You can override class but not method. Those are static or volatile. Cos method can only return the value. So overriding the method has no sense. I hope this will turn you, if nothing, toward how it was meant to be. Inheritance is mechanism how polymorphism works.

My apologies for unintentional mistakes during too much data.