# Is Polymorphism same in JAVA & C++?

Tags: java, c++, oop, polymorphism

Is polymorphism same in C++ as it is in Java ? Also When we say polymorphism has static and dynamic types, does the same thing exist in C++?

Comment: The high-level concepts of OOP are language independent.   How they are implemented within the structure of each language differs.  Each OOP language has differences in semantics and syntax.  Computer languages evolve over time and adding new facilities is hard without breaking lots of existing code (millions of man-years worth); so sometimes new facilities are not added in the most elegant fashion.

Comment: Yes I know and understand that but Why is there general disagreement (imo) on whether polymorhpyism has types or not ?

Comment: The basic concept of polymorphism is independent of programming language.    The mechanics by which it is supported (e.g. code constructs to achieve polymorphism) differ in some subtle and also not-so-subtle ways between C++ and Java.  Programmers in each language - particularly novices, but there are some lousy teachers of both languages too - have a habit of describing/conflating the mechanisms of their chosen language as polymorphism.     BTW:   programming in C is not often considered equivalent to functional programming, so you're conflating concepts as well.

Comment: Can you add references to this _"...general disagreement..."_ please.

Comment: I cant add them irl converstation I had but I do have a link where a senior user does; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804559/can-polymorphysim-be-achived-using-composition-instead-of-inheritance-in-java?noredirect=1#comment90565619_51804559 (Little Santi answer and the comments I did below that)

Comment: People in different parts of the U.S. disagree on the generic name for Coca Cola's beverage products.  "Soda", "pop", "coke" (used generically) ....  In a similar way, people in academic circles disagree on terminology and even essential definitions of terms such as "polymorphism".  This can come as a surprise to people who assume that such terms each have a single, precise meaning everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

One aspect between OOP in Java and C++ is Interface realisation and multiple inheritence.

While most OO-Languages (java, C#, etc.) support native Interfaces and forbid multiple inheritence C++ works just the other way.

C++ does not have Interfaces but only classes. If you want to imitate an Interface you'll have to write a class with only pure virtual methods and inherit it. There is no problem with that since C++ allows you to inherit multiple **Classes** which other OO-Languages don't. (One class, unlimited interfaces in java).

However, just because C++ allows you multiple inheritence you should be cautious about it. Inheriting multiple non-pure-virtual classes(non-interfaces) can easily produce spagetti code and lots of people even consider it as anti-pattern.

Comment: It might be more accurate to say "a class with only pure virtual methods" than "a pure virtual class" since there isn't any way to specify a pure virtual class in C++ - that would be an interface in other languages.

Comment: @Dave Doknjas - You are right. I adaped your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another strong difference (in addition with C++ multiple inheritance) will come with specialization of classes. Java uses generics (one single class for all specializations) while C++ uses templates (one different class for each specialization). As C++ fellows are often fond of this templating system, it can lead to different design patterns between Java and C++.

Comment: And it can make your Application unexpectedly large if you reuse big template classes without knowing this. Uncritical with desktop development but the embedded dudes should always keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand polymorphism is characterized by a few common characteristics namely:

- **Inheritance**

C++ supports multiple inheritance where Java does not, and C# does not.

- **Function Overloading**

Function overloading is supported in Java, C++ and C#.

- **Operator Overloading**

In C++ you can overload different operators so that they do different things for user defined types. 
Take for example the  << operator in C++:

```
cout << "First sentence." << endl;
```

The << operator is used to perform bitwise shifts in C, but std::ostream overloads these operators.

Not supported in Java but does support the '+' operator for concatenating strings. 
It is also worth noting that operator overloading is just a specialized kind of function overloading.

The fact that these are all OO languages, but don't necessarily handle each of these the same way may be what causes some disagreement about what polymorphism is.

Comment: Operator Overloading is just a special kind of function overloading because operators are functions. At least for classes. Primitive Datatypes are something different but they aren't inheritable either.

Comment: The `<<` operator isn't overloaded by `C++` but by `std::ostream`. `<<` does not always cause console output but is used by standard streams to insert elements. std::cout just happens to be a object of `std::ostream` ore one of it's children.

Comment: Good point. I'm new to stack overflow, should I edit my post to fix that up?

Comment: Yes. Improving one's answer's quality always should be the way.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Detonar